# Pass array data to batchWriteItem

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have this and it works fine:

```
$response = $dynamodb->batchWriteItem([
      'RequestItems' => [
         'my_table' => [
            [
                'PutRequest' => [
                  'Item' => ['ID' => ['N' => '120']]
                ],
                'PutRequest' => [  ///Entire PutRequest array need to be repeated not just item array///
                  'Item' => ['ID' => ['N' => '125']]
                ]
            ]
        ],
    ]
]);
```

How can I pass an array to my_table?

Comment: What array can you elaborate?

Comment: The PutRequest. How can I combine all PutRequest in an array? It is easy to type when I have 2 entries. But when I have 200 entries to insert...

Comment: I am unsure of that but, if you have data in CSV format then you can import it directly :)

Comment: The code is running on a _stream_. As the data comes in, it inserts the entries. Sometimes it is only 1 entry, sometimes there are 50 entries. Instead of using `putItem`, inserting one by one with multiple requests, I want to use `batchWriteItem` to insert, well, in a batch with a single request.